# Config Alpinejs in ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, alpine.js

Can someone explain to me how to configure alpinejs in an ASP.NET Core MVC project and use it in a my `.cshtml` files?

I have already run `npm install alpinejs` and I have already imported it into my `index.cstml` file

```
<script src="~/node_modules/alpinejs/dist/alpine.js"></script>
```

However I have a problem when I make `@click`

```
<button class="outline-none focus:outline-none border-r border-gray-200 w-10 h-10 hover:text-indigo-500 active:bg-gray-50" 
        @click="format('bold')">
    <i class="mdi mdi-format-bold"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the `@` is already a reserve symbol in asp.net, so you can escape it with `@@click` or use the longer binding syntax in Alpine of `x-on:click`