# I can't use Alpine.js @change,@submit and @keyup with ASP.NET Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, alpine.js

I'm using `Alpine.js` (included via CDN) in my `ASP.NET Razor Page`, but can't make it work.

[image: Code Screenshot]

VSCode shows an error: `CS0103: The name 'change' does not exist in the current context'`.

How can I use the `@change`, `@keyup` and `@submit` directives in my project?

Comment: Possible duplicate (same problem) of [Config Alpinejs in ASP.NET Core MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74869956/config-alpinejs-in-asp-net-core-mvc-project) with similar answer there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that in razor pages the @ sign is used to toggle between C# and HTML code. There are actually two solutions.

1. You can simply escape the `@` sign by typing `@@`

Taken from the alpine example page this would look like this

```
<button x-data @@click="$store.darkMode.toggle()">Toggle Dark Mode</button>

...

<div x-data :class="$store.darkMode.on && 'bg-black'">
    ...
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.store('darkMode', {
            on: false,

            toggle() {
                this.on = !this.on
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

The other solution would be to use the x-on Event coming with Alpine JS. you can change the click line to this:

```
<button x-data x-on:click="$store.darkMode.toggle()">Toggle Dark Mode</button>
```

This will have the same effect without the need to escape any characters. x-on can also work with Change, KeyUp etc. Just pick whatever solution you like best!